# Is Istio likely to support Envoy's hash ring load balancing algorithm?

Tags: envoyproxy, istio

## Short version:

Can I use Envoy's hash ring load balancing algorithm with Istio? Is this on the roadmap?

## More info:

The Istio load balancing docs [here](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/load-balancing.html) list the currently available load balancing algorithms.

I'd like to be able to use Envoy's hash ring load balancing algorithm but that isn't currently listed.

Why? I want to send grpc rpc's to the same kubernetes pods each time based on a shard key, in order to cache at that node/pod data needed for future requests. I've used the go library groupcache to do this before and that's worked well but I want to explore if it's possible with Istio as I imagine it would be a better way to do it for various reasons.

I'm hoping someone involved with or knowledgeable about the project can comment on whether a hash ring load balancer is on the Istio roadmap or is likely to be added, and if so roughly in what timeline. Also if there's a way to do it currently i'd love to pointed in the right direction.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> > Can I use Envoy's hash ring load balancing algorithm with Istio?

That load balancing algorithm is not currently supported.

> > Is this on the roadmap?

Yes. As part of next release.